# How can I permanently set keyboard layout via localectl?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, setxkbmap, localectl

I am using the niche keyboard layout EurKEY on my system (EndeavourOS, i3wm). Setting it works using the command `setxkbmap eu`. However, this ia valid for the current session only. According to Arch wiki `localectl eu` should make it permanent. It does not work though. There is no error but I still have us layout. Since localectl does not list `eu` as a layout, this is to be expected, I guess. However, I could not figure out, how to correctly set EurKEY via `localectl`. It might be related to the fact that keyboard-config has EurKEY as an exotic layout in `base.extra.xml`, but I am not sure. I could just put `setxkbmap eu` in `.xsession`, but according to what I found online, `localectl` is to be preferred. What is the best way to make EurKEY permanent?